# Embedded YouTube video showinfo incompatible with modestbranding?

Tags: html, youtube, embed, youtube-api

I'm embedding a YouTube video on my site with the parameter `modestbranding=1`. Unfortunately, I also want to use the parameter `showinfo=0`. When I tried this, it seems like the `modestbranding` doesn't work any more.

I've done research and found that `modestbranding` only works when it's the first parameter in the set, which I'm making sure to do.

I've also read that I can fake it by using the undocumented `title` parameter (see http://www.reelseo.com/remove-youtube-logo/), but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two parameters are mutually exclusive--sorry. We'll get https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#modestbranding updated to reflect that.

Comment: The specs still do not state this behavior