# How to remove youtube water mark on the bottom right of the player

Tags: html, css, youtube, sencha-touch-2, watermark

Can any one please let me know how to remove youtube's watermark or the click event of the watermark in the player

```
<embed id="player" style="height:50vh;" width="100%"     src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/DCTJCQ3uN1g?feature=youtube_gdata&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893902/how-to-remove-youtube-branding-after-embedding-video-in-web-page

Answer (score 0):

You can't. But if you don't need your video to be controled, you can simply add a

```
<div style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%"></div>
```

as a cover to prevent the <*iframe*> from hover event.

and you have to write your <*iframe*> item like

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="720" height="405" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
```

Then the water mark will get disappear in 3 seconds