# is there a way to hide youtube logo from youtube player embedded in iOS?

Tags: ios, youtube-api

I have embedded youtube using javascript api in my application and its showing the youtube logo on the bottom right , by clicking that logo it loads the youtube interface in the iframe , all I want is to disable that logo or its functionality , I have tried modestbranding in playervars but its not working

Comment: here is my sample code.

<iframe src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@?modestbranding=1&enablejsapi=1&rel=0&playsinline=1&autoplay=1&showinfo=0' frameborder='0'>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove youtube branding after embedding video in web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893902/how-to-remove-youtube-branding-after-embedding-video-in-web-page)

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove it completelly.

you need to contact youtube and probably pay them to remove their logo or replace it with a custom one in any of their videos.

you can hide it using  ?modestbranding=1 to your url. That will remove the logo temporany until mouseover on the video.

> modestbranding (supported players: AS3, HTML5)
>
> This parameter lets you use a YouTube player that does not show a YouTube logo. Set the parameter value to 1 to prevent the YouTube logo from displaying in the control bar. Note that a small YouTube text label will still display in the upper-right corner of a paused video when the user's mouse pointer hovers over the player.

Comment: modestbranding is not working for me , it although removes the logo but as mentioned in the documentation it comes back on hovering or highlighting the player ,

Comment: yes as i state at the start of the answer you can't remove completelly.