# youtube embedded video remove logo

Tags: javascript, youtube-iframe-api

I have the following page: http://www.alessandrosantese.com/test/aldemair-productions/

I would like to remove the bottom youtube logo, this is what I have so far:

```
            function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                player = new YT.Player('player', {
                    height: '390',
                    width: '640',
                    videoId: 'r8ZJ-4A1rxY',
                    playerVars: { 
                        'autoplay': 0,
                        'controls': 0, 
                        'rel' : 0,
                        'showinfo': 0,
                        'modestbranding': 1,
                        'fs': 0
                    },
                    events: {
                        'onReady': onPlayerReady
                    }
                });
            }
```

the logo is still there as you can see.

Comment: The link you've posted has `modestbranding` set to `0`, unlike the code you've posted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove youtube branding after embedding video in web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893902/how-to-remove-youtube-branding-after-embedding-video-in-web-page)

Answer (score 0):

You are already using `modestbranding`

> This parameter lets you use a YouTube player that does not show a
>   YouTube logo. Set the parameter value to 1 to prevent the YouTube logo
>   from displaying in the control bar. Note that a small YouTube text
>   label will still display in the upper-right corner of a paused video
>   when the user's mouse pointer hovers over the player.

And it does work on the site you provide - the logo disappears if you do not hover over the player.

It's probably against the usage policy of YouTube to remove their logo fully. There is no parameter on the standard YouTube player to do so.

In case you own the content, just host it on your own and use another player.

That's all you can do - at least legally.

Comment: `modestbranding` is an official parameter https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#modestbranding

Comment: I did and now undid. Your answer was previously just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `?modestbranding=1` to your url. That will remove the logo.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/url?modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vL3r9m08/)

Answer (score 0):

On certain devices (android tablet - but i did not look at all devices), note that if showinfo=0, then modestbranding=1 will not work - the logo will still be visible in the bottom right of the embed.  On a desktop it works however.