# How to remove watermark logo / brand logo and top title from youtube video?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-data-api

I want to add youtube video on website. I want, There will have only control panel. and need to hide top title and logo.
But If hide the title, then never hide logo / watermark logo.
But I need to hide twice (title+logo).
How can I do this ?

This is my code:

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Oo00q-l8VKQ?modestbranding=1&autoplay=0&rel=0&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Comment: What have you tried?  What did a search of stackoverflow yield? You don't start your research here.  You post here when your research fails and after stating what you have done so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove youtube branding after embedding video in web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893902/how-to-remove-youtube-branding-after-embedding-video-in-web-page)

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 Of course I was  research here and fail,
You should notice that, I want to remove Logo+Title together.
Your suggest link only for logo remove.

Now you can help me, How can I remove Logo+title together.

-Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try try this [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/mikemars/n923kp00/)

```css
<style>
 .video-wrapper {height: 153px; width: 272px; position: relative; overflow:hidden}
  #YouTubeVideo1 {height: 262px; width: 272px; position: absolute; margin-top:-55px}
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="video-wrapper">
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="272" height="252"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M5h3U_nNn3k?autoplay=1&controls=0&fs=0&rel=0&showinfo=0"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you should have read from [HERE](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters), it is not possible to remove ALL branding from the player window.

It is a corporate product that they have made. As such they advertise that it is their player (from their site) for their use with sharing functionality for us.

Considering the work that goes into a product like the YT-Player, and that they give us so much access to the api. I think it is reasonable.

If you do not want any branding, you should have your own player and content.