# Block you tube embed's you tube logo?

Tags: javascript, php, youtube, embed

I am using this you tube embed

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" style="box-shadow:0px 0px 5px black;"  type="text/html" width="100%" height="350" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo$youtube_video_id;?>?autoplay=1&showinfo=0&loop=0&modestbranding=1&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I want to remove youtube logo.
So is there any way to block this image?

```
https://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/watermark_ringo-vflPWbiPS.png
```

this is image of player
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vw33.png)

Comment: What have you tried? Please show us your attempt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove youtube branding after embedding video in web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893902/how-to-remove-youtube-branding-after-embedding-video-in-web-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add ?modestbranding=1 to the url to remove this logo.

Example:

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_K2cH74f8MU?modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: already did :)but still logo is showing in right part of player

Comment: @SuccessBureau Edited with example