# How does Khan Academy not show related videos?

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

I am curious how Khan Academy does not show related videos for their iFrame embed of Youtube in both the following cases:

1. On Pause.
2. And at the end of the video.

A sample of Khan Academy videos are here.

I know that Google/YouTube ended support of rel=0 back in October 2018 - but thats not the point. How does Khan Academy do it. See the video here:

https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/x2f8bb11595b61c86:solve-equations-inequalities

PS. I have done my research and seen:

[Is there a way of hiding related Youtube videos on pause with iframe api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55928042/is-there-a-way-of-hiding-related-youtube-videos-on-pause-with-iframe-api)
But I am trying to see exactly how Khan Academy (and apparently Stanford too) does it - I'm pretty sure they are following the Youtube TOS carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to implement the iframe player but without the "related videos" section. Researched a lot on ways to do that, some of them were:

1. Just don't show the player when paused
2. Cover the player's part with an empty, transparent div where the recommendations show up

But the cons of these ways were that they decreased the overall User Experience Quality for the website.

Seeing the way parameter "rel=0" works is that it filters out the suggestions of other youtube channel videos to just show videos of the youtube channel of which, the video is being played in the iframe player.

But if all videos are unlisted in the youtube channel, and then you use the "rel=0" parameter, It won't recommend them at all. Maybe because we instructed it to show related videos of the youtube channel of the current video but there aren't any listed ones to show on that channel.

This could mean they maybe have another youtube channel with all of their videos but unlisted.

Please correct me if I'm wrong :)
I hope this helped.