# Play youtube videos without logo

Tags: react-native, youtube, video-player, react-native-video

I need to play youtube videos in the react native app

I am using this

```
npm i react-native-youtube

npm i react-native-video
```

But these are not working fine for me. As i am playing videos i am getting youtube logo and options that indicates that this is a youtube video. So i want to hide youtube logo and everything that indicates that this is a youtube. But i want player controls like quality, duration, play, pause, resume, seekbar for forwards and change play duration. So please let me know how i can achieve it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove youtube branding after embedding video in web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893902/how-to-remove-youtube-branding-after-embedding-video-in-web-page)