# How to remove Youtube logo/next and recommended videos using javascript API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

im using Youtube API (not embedded) for video player on page with custom modfications.

I tried remove recommended videos by "playerVars: {rel: 0, showinfo: 0, ecver: 2}", but there are still showing black bar with "next videos".

```
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="player"></div>
<script>
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '1000',
    width: '100%',
    videoId: 'myID',
playerVars: {rel: 0, showinfo: 0, ecver: 2},
  });
}
(function($){
$(document).on('mouseover', '#player', function() {
player.mute();
  player.playVideo();
});
$(document).on('mouseout', '#player', function() {
  player.pauseVideo();
});})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Also is possible hide Youtube branding (logo) from the player?

Comment: So - you want to hide the fact that it's a youtube video?

Comment: Yes, it should be video banner, not embedded video

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove youtube branding after embedding video in web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893902/how-to-remove-youtube-branding-after-embedding-video-in-web-page)

Comment: No, because this is not embedded.

Comment: Maybe need some jquery to hide external css elements?