# Removing youtube watermark from youtube player

Tags: youtube, media-player

How can I remove youtube watermark in youtube player or please suggest me any other player in which youtube watermark can be removed, while playing youtube videos.

```
player = new YT.Player('playerId',
{
        width: getParameterByName('width'),
        height: getParameterByName('height'),
        html5: 1,
        videoId: getParameterByName('videoid'),
        playerVars: {'enablejsapi':1,'rel':0,'playsinline':1 ,'autoplay': parseInt(getParameterByName('auto')),'showinfo':0, 'controls': parseInt(getParameterByName('ctrl')),'wmode':'transparent', 'modestbranding':1 ,'color':'white','frameborder':0},
        events:
        {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
                'onError':onPlayerError
        }
});
```

I added the particular key 'modestbranding':1 in my code but nothing is changed, still I am getting the youtube icon at bottom right corner.

Here I am adding a screenshot of my video.
[image]

Comment: When you embed the player you can set the modestbranding flag: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=en#modestbranding

Comment: Accidentally flagged for wrong duplicate. Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893902/how-to-remove-youtube-branding-after-embedding-video-in-web-page

Comment: @Ciccio Thank you for your response, when I added same to my code nothing was changed. I edited my question and added code please check once.

Comment: This can have several causes, one of them being `Note: Setting the color parameter to white will disable the modestbranding option.` (from the documentation)

Comment: After removing color parameter also nothing is changed...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537535/embedded-youtube-video-showinfo-incompatible-with-modestbranding this post seems to give some more pointers, including it being incompatible with `showinfo` (and that modestbranding should be the first flag, but I have no idea of this)

Comment: Thank you for your support but it also dint work, if I made showinfo=1 then icon got hide. But I don't want to see the info too. Please update here if you get any useful stuff regarding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove youtube branding after embedding video in web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893902/how-to-remove-youtube-branding-after-embedding-video-in-web-page)